# How do I complete file paths in emacs?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, elisp

Say for instance I'm editing a config file and I want to type in a path.  Is there a plugin for emacs that lets you complete a file path in that buffer?  I've searched for this and there's like a bazillion completion plugins out there.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you area asking here. Modern emacen have path completion in the mini-buffer (when using `find-file` for instance). Do you want a similar behavior in a content buffer?

Comment: @dmckee - Yes, that's actually exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @dmckee Is this OS specific? I had file name completion in Find File in ubuntu but there is no completion in OSX. For instance I have a file called "reference" in root and I am in mini buffer: "Find file: ~/" and I enter "ref" and I expect completion but nothing happens. Do I need to install something?

Comment: @Zeynel Works fine for me in Mac OS, too. Either with the Apple installed version or the homebrew version. Also worked with the fink version on my older machine.

Comment: @dmckee Strange. Maybe I ask a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try [Hippie Expand](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HippieExpand), which as one of it's possibilities has '`try-complete-file-name`.  You can change the order and list of expansion functions hippie expand will use to favor expanding the file name.

Or, you could even write a custom wrapper that would only do the file name expansion.  Something like:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-/") 'my-expand-file-name-at-point)
(defun my-expand-file-name-at-point ()
  "Use hippie-expand to expand the filename"
  (interactive)
  (let ((hippie-expand-try-functions-list '(try-complete-file-name-partially try-complete-file-name)))
    (call-interactively 'hippie-expand)))
```

Answer (score 19):

I usually type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> like I would open a file, but instead of pressing <kbd>RET</kbd> I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> to copy the path and then paste it into the buffer I was editing with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd>.

I don't need this often enough, but if I really wanted a better solution, I would definitely use Trey Jackson's solution using `hippie-expand`.  I thought about how `hippie-expand` might be a better way to do this when first answering, but I didn't know and was too lazy to look it up, so I just wrote what *I* do.

Comment: Clunky and inelegant, but working. I have to admit to doing this from time to time myself. I'm still interested in a neater solution, though...

Comment: Indeed.  It doesn't really seem like a lot less work than typing it out manually though.

Comment: @Jason Baker: It depends on whether you know the exact file name or if you need to explore a bit for it.

Answer (score 12):

Up to version 25, the vanilla, out-of-the-box

```
M-x comint-dynamic-complete-filename
```

and

```
M-x comint-replace-by-expanded-filename
```

both worked outside of comint mode. Of course, you can use the minibuffer's dynamic expansion to use less keystrokes to get to them (e.g., M-x **comi**nt-**dy**namic-**c**omplete**-f**ilename or M-x **comi**nt-**rep**lace-by-expanded-**f**ilename). Or, if you will be doing this frequently, you can bind them to key sequences of your choice using `global-set-key` .

For version 26+, it seems to me that you need to make sure that comint mode is explicitly loaded --- adding a line

```
(require 'comint)
```

in your .emacs file should make this work again.

Caveat: Not all applicable comint functions can be used this way. comint-dynamic-list-filename-completions *doesn't* seem to work outside of its native mode.

Answer (score 5):

It is also possible to do this using the [company autocompletion](http://company-mode.github.io/) if the `company-files` are in the list of `company-backends` (default in my installation) or explicitly by calling `company-files`.

Comment: With Doom emacs, C-x C-f after typing the partial path, it works the charm!

Answer (score 2):

I recently discovered the works of Tomohiro Matsuyama (@m2ym) and I have been very impressed by the quality of its emacs packages.

I have struggled with most auto-completion extensions and found out that they all have major shortcomings.

Check out Tomo's auto-complete (http://auto-complete.org/doc/manual.html) it has been a breeze to install (I'm on Linux) and covers many auto-completion needs in a **modern** fashion.

Of course, your request for in-buffer file names completion is perfectly covered.

Finally, if you happen to do Ruby too, make sure not to miss his [RSense](http://cx4a.org/software/rsense/) extension; again, the best of its kind.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: And here is the new link: https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/blob/master/doc/manual.md